# Forwarding expressions in dots after manipulation while capturing environment

Tags: r, nse, rlang, tidyeval

I have a function `fun_1` that utilizes `substitute()` on its `...` argument, and another function `fun_2` with signature `fun_2(...)` that implements the pattern `do.call(fun_1, dots)`. I want `fun_1()` inside `fun_2()` to see the `...` passed to `fun_2()`. Here's an illustration of what I'm trying to do.

```
fun_1 <- function(...) {
  substitute(list(...))[-1] %>%
    sapply(deparse)
}
foo <- "X"
bar <- "Y"
fun_1(foo, bar)
# [1] "foo" "bar"

fun_2 <- function(...) {
  # dots <- Filter(length, ???)
  # rlang::invoke(my_fun, dots)
}
fun_2(foo, bar, NULL)
# desired output:
# [1] "foo" "bar"
```

I think there's enough magic in `rlang` to make this work but I'm having trouble figuring out how. I'm OK with modifying `fun_1` as long as

1. `fun_1()` has access to the values of `foo` and `bar`
2. The `do.call`
   pattern is implemented in `fun_2()`

EDIT: I also need `fun_2(list(foo, bar, NULL))` to work

Comment: Do you only want to filter out `NULL` only when its explicitly passed? or do you want to filter out `foo` if `is.null(foo)`?

Comment: @AdamSpannbauer the latter

Comment: I'm not sure I can help you because I don't understand what you're trying to achieve. If you want to forward dots after some manipulation, just take the dots in both functions with `exprs()`, `quos()`, `dots_list()` or `dots_splice()` depending on what you need, then forward them with `!!!`.

Comment: @lionel yep that's exactly what I needed! Things made more sense after I RTFM... for some reason I couldn't find the tidyeval vignette until a couple days ago.

Answer (score 1):

Possible solution using `pryr` & throwing out any 0 length elements passed.

#### using `do.call` & `fun_1`

```
fun_2 <- function(...) {
  #get dot values
  dot_vals   <- list(...)
  #get dot names as passed
  dot_names  <- pryr::dots(...)
  #which dots' lengths == 0
  len_0_dots <- 0 == vapply(dot_vals, length, numeric(1))
  #drop length 0s and call fun_1
  do.call('fun_1', dot_names[!len_0_dots])
}

foo  <- "x"
bar  <- "y"
null <- NULL

fun_2(foo, bar, null, NULL)

[1] "foo" "bar"
```

#### using standalone `fun3`

```
fun_3 <- function(...) {
  #get dot values
  dot_vals   <- list(...)
  #get dot names as passed
  dot_names  <- pryr::dots(...)
  #which dots' lengths == 0
  len_0_dots <- 0 == vapply(dot_vals, length, numeric(1))
  #drop length 0s and convert to vec
  as.character(dot_names[!len_0_dots])
}

foo  <- "x"
bar  <- "y"
null <- NULL

fun_3(foo, bar, null, NULL)

[1] "foo" "bar"
```

Comment: Thanks! This is definitely helpful and I think gets me closer. I had an omission which was that the function would also need to take lists as inputs... I've edited the OP

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing it this way:

```
fun_1 <- function(...) {
  substitute(list(...))[-1] %>%
    sapply(deparse) %>%
    gsub("~", "", .)
}
foo <- "X"
bar <- "Y"
fun_1(foo, bar)
# [1] "foo" "bar"

fun_2 <- function(...) {
  nonempty <- rlang::dots_splice(...) %>%
    sapply(Negate(rlang::is_empty)) %>%
    which()
  envir <- rlang::caller_env()
  quosures <- rlang::dots_exprs(...) %>%
    lapply(function(x) if (rlang::is_lang(x))
      rlang::lang_tail(x) else x) %>%
    unlist() %>%
    lapply(rlang::new_quosure, env = envir) %>%
    `[`(nonempty)

  rlang::lang("fun_1", !!! quosures)  %>%
    rlang::eval_tidy()
}
fun_2(foo, bar, NULL)
# [1] "foo" "bar"
fun_2(list(foo, bar))
# [1] "foo" "bar"
fun_2(foo, list(bar))
# [1] "foo" "bar"
```

First I had to manipulate the expressions passed to `...`, then create quosures out of them using the correct environment, then construct a call to forward to `fun_1`.

Comment: I would strongly advise against this kind of implementation. Rather than analysing the calls and splice the expressions, I would evaluate them then flatten the actual lists. Then it will work reliably, including with other list constructors like `rlang::ll()` and with unquoted lists.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a cleaner way of doing it:

```
library("purrr")
library("rlang")

quo_list <- function(quo) {
  expr <- get_expr(quo)
  if (is_lang(expr, "list")) {
    args <- lang_args(expr)
    map(args, new_quosure, env = get_env(quo))
  } else {
    list(quo)
  }
}

fun2 <- function(...) {
  quos <- quos(..., .ignore_empty = "all")
  quos <- flatten(map(quos, quo_list))
  fun1(!!! quos)
}
fun1 <- function(...) {
  map(quos(...), quo_name)
}
```

However it is often a bad idea to parse expressions this way. The list-splicing implemented here will only work if the calls specifically mention `list()`, they won't work if they use `rlang::ll()` or if the user unquotes lists, or in many other situations. Since this is not a tidyeval implementation, maybe you should remove the tag?